# An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation:

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
This is what iam getting when i tries to upload a file to S3. It works fine for me in local with the same bucket.But when coming to heroku in production it shows the above error.Any helps are appreciated

```
    s3_path = 'zips' + '/' + str(user_id) + '.zip'
    zipdata = open(zip_file_path, 'rb').read()
    file = default_storage.open(s3_path, 'wb')
    file.write(zipdata)
    file.close()
    return s3_path
```

issue occurs when writing the file.(multipart upload operation)

```
        bucket = s3.Bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
       key = 'media/zips/' + str(self.request.user.id) + '.zip'

        objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
        if len(objs) > 0 and objs[0].key == key:
            print("Exists!")
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})

        else:
            print("Doesn't exist")
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'failed'})
```

this is my bucket policy

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "some_id",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

same issue with the list operation also..

so will that be any issue with the bucket or something else?Iam using celery and redis in heroku.i had configured the environment variables with aws cli..

Comment: A little out of context but please don't use set the principal on the bucket to be `"*",` - this is extremely dangerous. You've currently granted everyone full access to your s3 bucket - including the ability to delete the bucket.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find the solution?